# Azure B2C The "Identity Experience Framework" is missing in the portal

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C directory and can use the built-in policies in my application. I'd like to use the custom policies to add my own claim.

The issue is that I can't find where I can upload/download the XML files of the "Identity Experience Framework" as referenced here: [Upload the policies to your tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom). The "Identity Experience Framework" is missing

Is there some requirements for the directory/subscription for this feature to show up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#prerequisites) section of that document you referenced:

> To access custom policy editing, you need a valid Azure subscription linked to your tenant.

Put differently, if you haven't [linked your Azure AD B2C tenant to an Azure subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-how-to-enable-billing), the Identity Experience Framework button will not show up.

Comment: ha.. makes sense. I'll try it and comment back!

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. Any idea when is this released for production?

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll submit a pull request to make this more obvious in the doc. RE: production, I'd assume different features will graduate from preview at different times. I'd suggest voting fir the specific features you are interest in via the Azure AD B2C feedback forum (https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv). You'll also get updates in their timelines there.